# Error when I run rake db:migrate installing fedena

Tags: database, rake, fedena

I'm installing Fedena and have been struggling with it for two weeks now. When I run

`rake db:migrate`

I get this error

> database configuration does not specify adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Your description shows that some info is missing.

Update the MySQL database details in config/database.yml (under "development:")

make sure the line "adapter: mysql" available and then

run the command "bundle exec rake db:create". This would create the required database.